# mypy issues with abstract classes and dictionaries

Tags: python, abstract-class, mypy, abc

Greatings, consider the following code.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Interface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self) -> None:
        pass


class A(Interface):
    def method(self) -> None:
        pass


class B(Interface):
    def method(self) -> None:
        pass


mapping = {'A': A, 'B': B}


# does NOT pass mypy checks
def create_map(param: str) -> Interface:
    if param in mapping:
        return mapping[param]()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError()

# passes mypy checks
def create_if(param: str) -> Interface:
    if param == 'A':
        return A()
    elif param == 'B':
        return B()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

For some reason, `create_if` passes all `mypy` type checking, but `create_map` does not. The `reveal_type` for both functions is `'def (param: builtins.str) -> test.Interface'`.

The error I get is the same as if I were trying to instantiate an abstract class directly, which is weird [considering this reference for mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html#abstract-base-classes-and-multiple-inheritance).

```
error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'Interface' with abstract attribute 'method'
```

Also, if I make `mapping = {'A': A}` (i.e. remove `'B': B`) now `create_map` also passes.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: If you type your `mapping` (`mapping: Mapping[str, Type[Interface]] = {'A': A, 'B': B}`), things appear to work correctly. Credit to mypy issues [1843](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1843) and [3048](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3048) for showing this syntax. (Why `mapping = {'A': A}` works without this extends beyond my mypy knowledge, however.)

Comment: Not sure exactly how I missed issue 3048 when searching for a solution, it is almost exactly what I asked. Thanks!

Comment: "(Why mapping = {'A': A} works without this extends beyond my mypy knowledge, however.)" <- I would really like to know the answer to this :) I had the same problem over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741125/why-does-mypy-throw-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-when-it-is-not-being-ins/74741969#74741969

Answer (score 14):

Apparently all I was missing was the type annotation for the mapping.

```py
mapping: Mapping[str, Type[Interface]] = {'A': A, 'B': B}
```

Thanks @jonafato

Credit to mypy issues [1843](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1843) and [3048](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3048) for showing this syntax.