# Why is mypy trying to instantiate my abstract class in Python?

Tags: python, mypy

If I have a Python module like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

class ConcreteClass1(AbstractClass):
    def method(self):
        print("hello")

class ConcreteClass2(AbstractClass):
    def method(self):
        print("hello")

class ConcreteClass3(AbstractClass):
    def method(self):
        print("hello")

classes = [
    ConcreteClass1,
    ConcreteClass2,
    ConcreteClass3,
]

for c in classes:
    c().method()
```

And I hit it with `mypy test.py`, I get this:

```sh
test.py:27: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "AbstractClass" with abstract attribute "method"
```

The code runs without any issues though, and I can't see any issues in the logic.
At no point am I trying to instantiate the `AbstractClass` directly.

Some weird behavior I've noticed:

If, instead of a loop, I do this:

```py
...
ConcreteClass1().method()
ConcreteClass2().method()
ConcreteClass3().method()
```

mypy is happy.

Also, if, instead of 3 classes in the loop, I do 2:

```py
classes = [
    ConcreteClass1,
    ConcreteClass2,
    #ConcreteClass3,
]

for c in classes:
    c().method()
```

mypy is happy with that as well.
What's going on? Is this a mypy bug? If so, can I tell mypy to ignore this "problem"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears similar to [mypy issues with abstract classes and dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241721/mypy-issues-with-abstract-classes-and-dictionaries) - for some reason, mypy can't typecheck this properly without a type annotation on the list:

```
classes: list[Type[AbstractClass]] = [
    ConcreteClass1,
    ConcreteClass2,
    ConcreteClass3,
]
```

(Change `list` to `List` if you're on Python 3.8 or below)

You might want to file an issue for this bug on the mypy Github.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. [Bug submitted](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12624). BTW, your `list` should be `List`. I tried to submit a correction, but apparently the stackoverflow `Suggested edit queue is full`

Comment: @John It's a new feature in Python 3.9.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Awesome! Thanks